# jQuery css left, top, z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I have a few tests that test if the style params are set properly. For some reason, some tests fail in Chrome. Here are the tests. `element` is a jQuery Object by the way.

```
    equal(element.css("left"),  "41px", "left is set properly");
    equal(element.css("top"),  "144px", "top is set properly");
    equal(element.css("z-index"),  "2070", "z-index is set properly");
```

All three of them pass in Firefox but not in Chrome. When I put a breakpoint on the tests and inspect `element.css("left")` I get "41px". But the test still fails showing the following error. Does anybody know why ?

[image]

Comment: is the dom being modified in anyway by the one running the tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug, there is pull request that fixes this issue in jquery git repo
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1241

you can try to clone jquery repo, apply this patch and make custom build